# LIBGDX Framebuffer is drawn as a black box

Tags: libgdx, framebuffer

**We figured out the issue. I was disposing the framebuffer before using it.**

I recently queried about how to use the Libgdx [Framebuffer](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.java) correctly.

Summed up, i am making a tile-based game and i wanted to understand how to setup and use a
framebuffer object to eventually start experimenting with shaders. I wanted to exclude the
"water tiles" from the normal draw cycle and instead have them be rendered to a framebuffer.
Then render the framebuffer to the screen.

(I am not using any "Scene2d" or "Tiled" classes)

Link to previous question: [How to use LIBGDX FrameBuffer correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325259/how-to-use-libgdx-framebuffer-correctly).

Even though the answer i accepted did not work in my particular program, it did work
when i tried it out on a smaller more contained program (shown below).

**This works**:

```
public void render() {
    float dt = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    Cam.instance.getCamera().translate(direction.x*speed*dt, direction.y*speed*dt,0);
    Cam.instance.update();

    // clear the screen, set batch's projection matrix
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(Cam.instance.getCamera().combined);

    // draw texture as layer 0
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(green,606,306);

    batch.flush(); // No need to call batch.end() / batch.begin()

    // Storing the original values of the batch before changing it.
    originalMatrixTemp.set(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    int originalBlendSrcFunc = batch.getBlendSrcFunc();
    int originalBlendDstFunc = batch.getBlendDstFunc();

    // Sorcery as far as i am concerned. "Ensures alpha is preserved in case of overlapping translucent sprites"
    batch.setBlendFunctionSeparate(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE);


    frameBuffer.begin(); // initialize framebuffer
    // clear the colors of the batch
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.draw(red,256,0); // Draw another texture, now unto the framebuffer texture
    batch.flush(); // flush batch
    frameBuffer.end(); // end framebuffer

    // "Ensure we're drawing the frame buffer texture without modifying its color"
    batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    
    // I think we are setting the projection to "default" (-1,1,2,-2)
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(IDENTITY);
    
    // draw the framebuffers texture across all the screen (layer 1)
    batch.draw(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture(),-1, 1, 2, -2);
    batch.flush();
    
    // restoring the original state
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(originalMatrixTemp);
    batch.setBlendFunction(originalBlendSrcFunc, originalBlendDstFunc);

    // drawing arbitrary layer 2
    batch.draw(green,300,300);

    batch.end(); // end of cycle
}
```

and it shows (Red square is the framebuffer texture): [image: Arbitrary squares]

The cycle is: Begin -> Draw something -> Draw, using buffer -> Draw something -> end.

So my question is then, **why does this not work**:

```
private void renderFbo(int layer) {
    batch.flush();

    originalMatrixTemp.set(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    int originalBlendSrcFunc = batch.getBlendSrcFunc();
    int originalBlendDstFunc = batch.getBlendDstFunc();

    batch.setBlendFunctionSeparate(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE);

    fbo.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Drawing the layer unto the framebuffer:
    for (DrwDat dat: layers.get(layer)) { dat.draw(batch); }

    batch.flush();
    fbo.end();

    batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(IDENTITY);

    // Halving the output texture to see the issue clearer. whole screen: (-1, 1, 2, -2)
    batch.draw(fbo.getColorBufferTexture(), -0.5f, 0.5f, 1f, -1f);
    batch.flush();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(originalMatrixTemp);
    batch.setBlendFunction(originalBlendSrcFunc, originalBlendDstFunc);
}
```

With this being the immediate context:

```
public void draw() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1); // clearing with WHITE to see the framebuffer texture
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LAYERS; i++) {
        if (RENDER[i]) {
            if (SORT[i]) Collections.sort(layers.get(i));
            //for (DrwDat dat: layers.get(i)) { dat.draw(batch);}
            if (i==1) { renderFbo(i); } // calling the framebuffer-using method for "water layer"
            else{
                for (DrwDat dat: layers.get(i)) {
                    dat.draw(batch);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Instance variables in the "draw class" :

```
public class DrwHandler {

private static final String TAG = DrwHandler.class.getName();
public static DrwHandler instance = new DrwHandler();
private final Matrix4 originalMatrixTemp = new Matrix4();
private static final Matrix4 IDENTITY = new Matrix4();
private Map<Integer, ArrayList<DrwDat>> layers;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private FrameBuffer fbo;
private SpriteBatch batch;

private static final int NUM_LAYERS = 8;
private static final boolean[] RENDER = new boolean[NUM_LAYERS];
private static final boolean[] SORT = new boolean[NUM_LAYERS];

private DrwHandler() {
    fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, Settings.SCREEN_W,Settings.SCREEN_H,false);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    layers = new HashMap<>();
    layers.put(0,new ArrayList<>());
    layers.put(1,new ArrayList<>());
    layers.put(2,new ArrayList<>());
    layers.put(3,new ArrayList<>());
    layers.put(4,new ArrayList<>());
    layers.put(5,new ArrayList<>());
    layers.put(6,new ArrayList<>());
    layers.put(7,new ArrayList<>());
}
```

It shows: [image: black box]

The "black box" is the framebuffer texture (redused in size). The white background is the clear color.
and the green is a foreground layer.

It is black regardless of changing the Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0) within the context of the framebuffer rendering to some other color.

without the renderFbo() method, it renders normally like this:

[image: Without Buffer]

Now i have heard Static references can cause issues with OpenGL-related objects:

> "If you will be building for Android, never use static references to any OpenGL-related objects unless you have an expert understanding of the LibGDX lifecycle. Even then, it is an error-prone practice. People come on here to ask about black textures pretty frequently and 99% of the time it has to do with some static reference being used incorrectly."

I am not building for android. And since my previous question i have removed static objects.
just to be sure.

But i do use statics in a few select classes like this (example):

```
public class Cam {

public static Cam instance = new Cam();
private OrthographicCamera camera;

private Cam() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Settings.SCREEN_W, Settings.SCREEN_H);
}
```

(including my Assets class and Draw class):

Trying to think about what else.. I guess we will try with this first. Se if something sticks out to you.
Really could need some help right about now. Been banging my head against the wall for a while. Thank you.

Here is a link to some source files that could be relevant:

[Source](https://github.com/fre-dahl/test2)

Comment: I would highly recommend trying ending the batch, end the frameBuffer, then restart the batch before drawing the framebuffer. In your first example that 'works', there is a possibility that it is not working how you think it is and in fact there are bugs in that too. All I can say is I've used frameBuffers without any problem, but have always started a new SpriteBatch before drawing them out.

Comment: Have you tried using a clear color other than black for the frame buffer so we can rule out an issue with the frame buffer itself? That would also rule out anything to do with static references. Then try rendering a single texture right in front of the camera to rule out some unaccounted interaction from `Drwdat.draw()`. And can you show the code for `DrwDat.draw()`?

Comment: @funferret-com I tried replacing flush with begin/end. I don't think i can do anything
differently with the framebuffer? i call fbo.begin -> batch.begin -> clear -> draw -> batch.end -> fbo.end. The black box is still there. I think i got you, but could you give an example just in case?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes i did: after: fbo.begin() i call: Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1); still black. I also tried replacing this: for (DrwDat dat: layers.get(layer)) { dat.draw(batch); } with this: batch.draw(red,0,0,500,500); //(Texture) no change. And that texture is not part of the "drwDat" system. I will edit the question with a link to some sourcefiles.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, try making the clear color red, and draw *nothing* to the frame buffer. That would rule out that the black is coming from what you're drawing. Would be happy to look over your complete source.

Comment: Thanks. Thats really appreciated. @Tenfour04 Not all files are relevant mind you. i added some just in case. I am not using most of the drw classes. The relevant are drwdat and drwregion. I will try to change to a red clear-color and draw nothing. I am also very green to libgdx/programming.

Comment: Yep. I am drawing nothing with red clear color. Still a black rectangle

Comment: Can you show how you're instantiating the FrameBuffer in the simple project where it works?

Comment: https://github.com/fre-dahl/test3/blob/master/src/GameClass.java @tenfour04

Comment: In the simple program. I tried to make the camera static to see what would happen. It gave this error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4.mul(float[], float[])'  at com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4.mul(Native Method)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4.mul(Matrix4.java:319) at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera.update(OrthographicCamera.java:58) (and some more) point is. static is not exactly stable. Wish i knew what was happening begin the scenes

Comment: Camera uses Matrix4, which relies on native code so if you call its methods before LibGDX has a chance to load native libraries you get an UnsatisfiedLinkError. Still don’t see anything amiss in your code. If you wanted to post the entire project to GitHub I could run and debug it later.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I can do that. I included a info.txt to you in the Tenfour folder. Whats your username on Github so i can give you access?

Comment: Same username as here, lowercase.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Alrighty, just sent you an invite.

Comment: I found the issue. Check your github page for the project.

Comment: Voila. It works. commented on the issue :)